# How to add a loop in data table for each row in r?

Tags: r

dt <- data.table(dummy=rep(c(0:1),each=10), piece = rep(c(3:4)), values1=c(10:29), values2=c(20:39))

I have a data table like this. I want to achieve:
if dummy = 0, then create a new column to this data table whose new_value1 = (values1 + values2) * piece;
if dummy = 1, then create another new column whose new_value2 = value1 + value2 * piece
how could I realize this by using a loop in r?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a doubt.  For the rows that are 1 for dummy 0, the new_value1 would be `NA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We specify the condition in `i` and create those columns in `j`

```
library(data.table)
dt[dummy == 0, new_value1 := (values1 + values2) * piece
   ][dummy == 1, new_value2 := (values1 + values2) * piece]
```

---

Or another option is `dcast`

```
dt[, new_value :=  (values1 + values2) * piece]
dcast(dt, seq_len(nrow(dt)) + piece + values1 + values2 ~ 
      paste0('new_value', match(dummy, unique(dummy))))
```